# How to animate text over another View in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to animate some text 'zooming out' on top of another view.  My code looks something like:

```
class BoardView extends View {

private TextView animText;

...

private void animText(String text, int color, int xBlocks, int yBlocks) {
    animText.setText(text);
    animText.setTextColor(color);
    animText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    final int x = BOARD_X_OFFSET + xBlocks * xBlockSize;
    final int y = BOARD_Y_OFFSET + yBlocks * yBlockSize;
    final float SCALE_FROM = (float) 0.25;
    final float SCALE_TO = (float) 5.0;
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(SCALE_FROM, SCALE_TO, SCALE_FROM, SCALE_TO, x, y);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    animText.setAnimation(anim);
    this.setAnimation(null);
    startAnimation(anim);
}

}
```

with animText being invoked in the `onDraw()` routine of the `BoardView`.  What I'm seeing, however, is the *board* zooming out, not the text, despite the above calls to `setAnimation()`.

I've looked in the main android docs and at one other [example](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/).  Even pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm glad I'm not the only one who had a difficult time finding the very subtle bug in the above.  The bug is:

```
startAnimation(anim);
```

which isn't too obvious until you expand it into:

```
this.startAnimation(anim);
```

at which point it's clear why the outer view (ie. 'this') is animating as well as the text.